# JQuery parallax slider broken in Firefox

Tags: jquery, wordpress, firefox, slider

I have a slider on my Wordpress site that will no longer load on Firefox 49 or 50. The loading indicator comes up but won't animate or display and slides. Works fine in Chrome and IE. Below is the JQuery. Any reason why this would break in new versions of Firefox?

```
    (function($){$.fn.activity=function(opts){this.each(function(){var $this=$(this);var el=$this.data("activity");if(el){clearInterval(el.data("interval"));el.remove();$this.removeData("activity");}if(opts!==false){opts=$.extend({color:$this.css("color")},$.fn.activity.defaults,opts);el=render($this,opts).css("position","absolute").prependTo(opts.outside?"body":$this);var h=$this.outerHeight()-el.height();var w=$this.outerWidth()-el.width();var margin={top:opts.valign=="top"?opts.padding:opts.valign=="bottom"?h-opts.padding:Math.floor(h/2),left:opts.align=="left"?opts.padding:opts.align=="right"?w-opts.padding:Math.floor(w/2)};var offset=$this.offset();if(opts.outside){el.css({top:offset.top+"px",left:offset.left+"px"});}else{margin.top-=el.offset().top-offset.top;margin.left-=el.offset().left-offset.left;}el.css({marginTop:margin.top+"px",marginLeft:margin.left+"px"});animate(el,opts.segments,Math.round(10/opts.speed)/10);$this.data("activity",el);}});return this;};$.fn.activity.defaults={segments:12,space:3,length:7,width:4,speed:1.2,align:"center",valign:"center",padding:4};$.fn.activity.getOpacity=function(opts,i){var steps=opts.steps||opts.segments-1;var end=opts.opacity!==undefined?opts.opacity:1/steps;return 1-Math.min(i,steps)*(1-end)/steps;};var render=function(){return $("<div>").addClass("busy");};var animate=function(){};function svg(tag,attr){var el=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",tag||"svg");if(attr){$.each(attr,function(k,v){el.setAttributeNS(null,k,v);});}return $(el);}if(document.createElementNS&&document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","svg").createSVGRect){render=function(target,d){var innerRadius=d.width*2+d.space;var r=(innerRadius+d.length+Math.ceil(d.width/2)+1);var el=svg().width(r*2).height(r*2);var g=svg("g",{"stroke-width":d.width,"stroke-linecap":"round",stroke:d.color}).appendTo(svg("g",{transform:"translate("+r+","+r+")"}).appendTo(el));for(var i=0;i<d.segments;i++){g.append(svg("line",{x1:0,y1:innerRadius,x2:0,y2:innerRadius+d.length,transform:"rotate("+(360/d.segments*i)+", 0, 0)",opacity:$.fn.activity.getOpacity(d,i)}));}return $("<div>").append(el).width(2*r).height(2*r);};if(document.createElement("div").style.WebkitAnimationName!==undefined){var animations={};animate=function(el,steps,duration){if(!animations[steps]){var name="spin"+steps;var rule="@-webkit-keyframes "+name+" {";for(var i=0;i<steps;i++){var p1=Math.round(100000/steps*i)/1000;var p2=Math.round(100000/steps*(i+1)-1)/1000;var value="% { -webkit-transform:rotate("+Math.round(360/steps*i)+"deg); }\n";rule+=p1+value+p2+value;}rule+="100% { -webkit-transform:rotate(100deg); }\n}";document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(rule);animations[steps]=name;}el.css("-webkit-animation",animations[steps]+" "+duration+"s linear infinite");};}else{animate=function(el,steps,duration){var rotation=0;var g=el.find("g g").get(0);el.data("interval",setInterval(function(){g.setAttributeNS(null,"transform","rotate("+(++rotation%steps*(360/steps))+")");},duration*1000/steps));};}}else{var s=$("<shape>").css("behavior","url(#default#VML)").appendTo("body");if(s.get(0).adj){var sheet=document.createStyleSheet();$.each(["group","shape","stroke"],function(){sheet.addRule(this,"behavior:url(#default#VML);");});render=function(target,d){var innerRadius=d.width*2+d.space;var r=(innerRadius+d.length+Math.ceil(d.width/2)+1);var s=r*2;var o=-Math.ceil(s/2);var el=$("<group>",{coordsize:s+" "+s,coordorigin:o+" "+o}).css({top:o,left:o,width:s,height:s});for(var i=0;i<d.segments;i++){el.append($("<shape>",{path:"m "+innerRadius+",0  l "+(innerRadius+d.length)+",0"}).css({width:s,height:s,rotation:(360/d.segments*i)+"deg"}).append($("<stroke>",{color:d.color,weight:d.width+"px",endcap:"round",opacity:$.fn.activity.getOpacity(d,i)})));}return $("<group>",{coordsize:s+" "+s}).css({width:s,height:s,overflow:"hidden"}).append(el);};animate=function(el,steps,duration){var rotation=0;var g=el.get(0);el.data("interval",setInterval(function(){g.style.rotation=++rotation%steps*(360/steps);},duration*1000/steps));};}$(s).remove();}})(jQuery);



    (function($) {
            $.fn.parallaxSlider = function(options) {
                var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.parallaxSlider.defaults, options);
                return this.each(function() {
                    var $pxs_container  = $(this),
                    o               = $.meta ? $.extend({}, opts, $pxs_container.data()) : opts;

                    $("#menuContainer").activity({segments: 12, width:5.5, space: 6, length: 13, color: '#fff'});

                    //the main slider
                    var $pxs_slider     = $('.pxs_slider',$pxs_container),
                    //the elements in the slider
                    $elems          = $pxs_slider.children(),
                    //total number of elements
                    total_elems     = $elems.length,
                    //the navigation buttons
                    $pxs_next       = $('.pxs_next',$pxs_container),
                    $pxs_prev       = $('.pxs_prev',$pxs_container),
                    //the bg images
                    $pxs_bg1        = $('.pxs_bg1',$pxs_container),
                    //current image
                    current         = 0,
                    //the thumbs container
                    $pxs_thumbnails = $('.pxs_thumbnails',$pxs_container),
                    //the interval for the autoplay mode
                    slideshow,
                    //the loading image
                    //$pxs_loading  = $('.pxs_loading',$pxs_container),
                    $pxs_slider_wrapper = $('.pxs_slider_wrapper',$pxs_container);

                    //first preload all the images
                    var loaded      = 0,
                    $images     = $pxs_slider_wrapper.find('img');

                    $images.each(function(){
                        //ADD INDICATORS
                        $('.pxs_thumbnails').append("<li></li>");
                    });
                    //the thumbs
                    var $thumbs = $pxs_thumbnails.children();


                    $images.each(function(){

                        var $img    = $(this);
                        $('<img/>').load(function(){
                            ++loaded;
                            if(loaded   == total_elems/**2*/){
                                $("#menuContainer").activity(false);
                                //$pxs_loading.hide();
                                $('.pxs_bg .pxs_bg1').fadeIn(400);
                                $pxs_slider_wrapper.fadeIn(1200);

                                //one images width (assuming all images have the same sizes)
                                var one_image_w     = $pxs_slider.find('img:first').width();

                                setWidths($pxs_slider,
                                $elems,
                                total_elems,
                                $pxs_bg1,
                                one_image_w,
                                $pxs_next,
                                $pxs_prev);

                                //make the first thumb be selected
                                highlight($thumbs.eq(0));

                                //slide when clicking the navigation buttons
                                $pxs_next.bind('click',function(){
                                    ++current;
                                    if(current >= total_elems)
                                        if(o.circular)
                                            current = 0;
                                    else{
                                        --current;
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                    highlight($thumbs.eq(current));
                                    slide(current,
                                    $pxs_slider,
                                    $pxs_bg1,
                                    o.speed,
                                    o.easing,
                                    o.easingBg);
                                    $thumbs.fadeOut(100).delay(1000).fadeIn(400);
                                });
                                $pxs_prev.bind('click',function(){
                                    --current;
                                    if(current < 0)
                                        if(o.circular)
                                            current = total_elems - 1;
                                    else{
                                        ++current;
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                    highlight($thumbs.eq(current));
                                    slide(current,
                                    $pxs_slider,
                                    $pxs_bg1,
                                    o.speed,
                                    o.easing,
                                    o.easingBg);
                                    $thumbs.fadeOut(100).delay(1000).fadeIn(400);
                                });

                                /*
                                clicking a thumb will slide to the respective image
                                 */
                                $thumbs.bind('click',function(){
                                    var $thumb  = $(this);
                                    highlight($thumb);
                                    //if autoplay interrupt when user clicks
                                    if(o.auto)
                                        clearInterval(slideshow);
                                    current     = $thumb.index();
                                    slide(current,
                                    $pxs_slider,
                                    $pxs_bg1,
                                    o.speed,
                                    o.easing,
                                    o.easingBg);
                                    $thumbs.fadeOut(100).delay(1000).fadeIn(400);
                                });

                                /*
                                activate the autoplay mode if
                                that option was specified
                                 */
                                if(o.auto != 0){
                                    o.circular  = true;
                                    slideshow   = setInterval(function(){
                                        $pxs_next.trigger('click');
                                    },o.auto);
                                }
                                //RESIZE
                                $(window).resize(function(){
                                    w_w = $(window).width();
                                    setWidths($pxs_slider,$elems,total_elems,$pxs_bg1,one_image_w,$pxs_next,$pxs_prev);
                                    slide(current,
                                    $pxs_slider,
                                    $pxs_bg1,
                                    1,
                                    o.easing,
                                    o.easingBg);
                                });
                            }
                        }).error(function(){
                            alert('here')
                        }).attr('src',$img.attr('src'));
                    });
                });
            };

            //the current windows width
            var w_w             = $(window).width();

            var slide           = function(current,
            $pxs_slider,
            $pxs_bg1,
            speed,
            easing,
            easingBg){
                var slide_to    = parseInt(-w_w * current);
                $pxs_slider.stop().animate({
                    left    : slide_to + 'px'
                },speed, easing);
                $pxs_bg1.stop().animate({
                    left    : slide_to/8 + 'px'
                },speed, easingBg);
            }

            var highlight       = function($elem){
                $elem.siblings().removeClass('selected');
                $elem.addClass('selected');
            }

            var setWidths = function($pxs_slider,
            $elems,
            total_elems,
            $pxs_bg1,
            one_image_w,
            $pxs_next,
            $pxs_prev){
                /*
                the width of the slider is the windows width
                times the total number of elements in the slider
                 */
                var pxs_slider_w    = w_w * total_elems;
                $pxs_slider.width(pxs_slider_w + 'px');
                //each element will have a width = windows width
                $elems.width(w_w + 'px');
                /*
                we also set the width of each bg image div.
                The value is the same calculated for the pxs_slider
                 */
                $pxs_bg1.width(pxs_slider_w + 'px');

            }

            $.fn.parallaxSlider.defaults = {
                auto        : 0,    //how many seconds to periodically slide the content. If set to 0 then autoplay is turned off.
                speed       : 1200, //speed of each slide animation
                easing      : 'jswing', //easing effect for the slide animation
                easingBg    : 'jswing', //easing effect for the background animation
                circular    : true //circular slider
            };
            //easeInOutExpo,easeInBack
        })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you add simple a running example? Are there any error in the JS-console?

Comment: FF 50.1.0 says: `TypeError: Not enough arguments to CSSStyleSheet.insertRule`

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas how to fix this? I don't know much JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the API is calling a function with one argument.

This is deprecated by Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule

and is causing a Error: `TypeError: Not enough arguments to CSSStyleSheet.insertRule`

You could try adding the index to insertRule (0 in this case)

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(rule, 0)
```